# CSS won't run on phone browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've tried making a website and on the computer it works just fine but when i open the website on my phone id won't run the css..

---

The css that is not running is the one with the triangles that make the transfer to to background

---

i've tried searching it but it seems that there are different answers for multiuple cases

you can check on andrei-marin.com i have the website running

*EDIT: it runst just fine google chrome and firefox but wont work on safari on laptop!
This is The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reveal content animation (and menu)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style2.css">


</head>

<body>

  <header>
  <div class="triangle left"><div class="typewriter"><h1>Andrei Marin</h1></div></div>
  <div class="triangle right"><div class="typewriter"><h1>Andrei Marin</h1></div></div>
  <button></button>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Projects</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="nav-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
</nav>

<content>
  <section>Home</section>
  <section>About</section>
  <section>Projects</section>
  <section>Contact</section>
</content>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>



    <script  src="./script.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 300vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cdcdcd 0%, #818181 100%);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header h1, header button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

header button {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #09203f;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1), transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955), box-shadow 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  overflow: hidden;
}
header button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
header button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
header button:before, header button:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  top: 17px;
  position: absolute;
}
header button:before {
  content: "\f067";
  opacity: 1;
  left: 53px;
}
header button:after {
  content: "\f0c9";
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #09203f 0%, #537895 100%);
  background: url('bg.jpg');
  height: 100%;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
header .triangle.left {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
header .triangle.right {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
header.open .triangle.left {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
}
header.open .triangle.right {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
header.open button {
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
header.open button:before {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
header.open button:after {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 18px;
}
header.open button.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
header.open button.menu:after {
  left: -100%;
}

content section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2pt;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1pt;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #09203f;
  animation: fadeDown .5s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
}
nav ul li:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: .8;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
nav #nav-close {

  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: fadeDown .5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #09203f;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
@keyframes fadeDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation:
    typing 3.5s steps(30, end),
    blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: white }
}
```

This is the JS:

```
// function to open/close nav
function toggleNav(){
  // if nav is open, close it
  if($("nav").is(":visible")){
    $("nav").fadeOut();
    $("button").removeClass("menu");
  }
  // if nav is closed, open it
  else{
    $("button").addClass("menu");
    $("nav").fadeIn().css('display', 'flex');
  }
}

// when clicking + or ☰ button
$("button").click(function(){
  // when clicking ☰ button, open nav
  if($("header").hasClass("open")){
    toggleNav();
  }
  // when clicking + button, open header
  else{
    $("header").addClass("open");
  }
});

// close nav
$("#nav-close").click(function(){
  toggleNav();
});

// scroll to sections
$("nav li").click(function(){
  // get index of clicked li and select according section
  var index = $(this).index();
  var target = $("content section").eq(index);

  toggleNav();

  $('html,body').delay(300).animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Anyone knowing how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the data for the browser on your phone. It's working fine and could be an issue with the browser not reloading the CSS. You can also temporarily change the stylesheet URL so the browser is forced to grab it again.

[image]

Seems more like an issue with your device. Also in chrome try `F12` and `disable cache` in the networking setting and try viewing with the mobile device presets.

Comment: The thing is not this, the home screen works fine but if you ckick on the button, it wont bring you to the page.. Try going on a computer and press the button and see what happens then try chicking it on the phone :)